# Guest Order Summary - GuestOrderStatus.Service.ss

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

We want to create a page/module that will let the users view the 'order summary' after entering the order id + email address.

The page will part of shopping app and the url will be something like this:

www.mywebsite.com/guestordersummary

We are using the 'GuestOrderStatus' suite solution which returns 'Order Status'

We need to display the following fields:

1. Sub Total
2. Shipping cost
3. Tax
4. Grand total

The 'ordersummary' object has the above information 
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27519/kw/ORDERSUMMARY

The 'getOrderSummary' method returns this object but it is only available through the getShoppingSession()

eg: nlapiGetWebContainer().getShoppingSession().getOrder().getOrdeSummary(['itemcount']);

How do we enable access to the service 'GuestOrderStatus.Service.ss' to non logged-in user?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the file GuestOrderStatus.Service.ss in your File Cabinet Find the Check box "AVAILABLE WITHOUT LOGIN" and then check that one.

You should see it in the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Romeo,

We already tried it.

We even assigned a 'custom role' with permission on 'sales order'

Comment: and still no luck?

Comment: No bro! No Luck!

Comment: hmmmm that really needs some further investigation bro.